# How to extend/remove timeout for GitHub GraphQL queries being called by the Apollo Client in the server side of the Next.JS application?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, apollo-client

I'm trying to load a server side render page from my Next.JS app. Unfortunately, the GraphQL API's performance is intermittent and a timeout error is being returned if there's no response after 10 seconds. Sometimes it does respond in less than 10, though. But I only encounter this on the server side. When I query directly via an API client, or even the useQuery hooks from the Apollo Client package (which is being called in the browser side), no timeout is being returned. I suspect that it has something to do with the lack of explicitly setting the timeout for the server side. I just don't know where. I've tried everything I got my hands on from Google Search and ChatGPT. I badly need your help.

This is the error:

```
{
  "name": "ApolloError",
  "graphQLErrors": [],
  "protocolErrors": [],
  "clientErrors": [],
  "networkError": {
    "cause": {
      "name": "ConnectTimeoutError",
      "code": "UND_ERR_CONNECT_TIMEOUT",
      "message": "Connect Timeout Error"
    }
  },
  "message": "fetch failed"
}
```

I already tried adding `HTTP_SERVER_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT=0` in my .env.local file. Also tried adding this in the next.config.js

```
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/[:path]*',
        headers: [
          {
            key: 'Request-Timeout',
            value: '30000',
          }
        ],
      },
    ]
  },
```

Tried adding `ssrMode: true` in my apollo client.

**EDIT:
**
I tried making a mock REST API with a delay of 20s

```
const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3001/test`)
```

and fetched it in the getServerSideProps. Doesn't seem to encounter the timeout error.